# is there any way to have DataSent Event in c#?

Tags: c#, serial-port, interrupt

Is there any way to have a data-sent (TX buffer empty or "UART Transmit Complete" ) event in c#, as is available in lower level languages?

This is a part of a university project that explicitly require the use of "UART Transmit Complete"  interrupt

Comment: It might be useful to the folks trying to answer your question if you told us a little bit about your code and what you're trying to accomplish with it.

Answer (score 3):

The operating system does have a signal for that, WaitCommEvent() with the EV_TXEMPTY option.  But that wasn't exposed in the SerialPort class at all.  What you've got is the BytesToWrite property, it tells you how many bytes are left in the transmit buffer.  No event, you'd have to poll it with a timer.

Not exposing the EV_TXEMPTY event in the SerialPort class was no doubt intentional, it would have been extremely easy to add it.  The trouble with that event is that it is quite useless to know anything that's going on with the serial port.  It only says that the transmit buffer is empty, it does **not** say anything about whether the port is done sending data.  Modern UART chips have a buffer on the chip, typically 16 bytes deep, that stores bytes just before they are sent.  Useful to lower the interrupt overhead and avoid gaps between the bytes.  There is *no* signal at all that says that his buffer is empty as well.  It was never added to the native driver interface.

It is entirely unclear why you need this.  The message is clear, you do not want to need this.